# Rewrite a query Parameter in a Sub Directory in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Please help me rewrite from a subdirectory with parameter to another directory using htaccess. Edit: I should note that the parameter will be from user input so I need a wild card where the keyword is.

From
http://www.example.com/search/node?find=keyword

To
http://www.example.com/search/node/keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following rule in /root.htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
#1)Redirect "/search/node/?find=foo" to "/search/node/foo"#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search/node/?\?find=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search/node/%1? [NC,L,R]
#2)internally redirect "/search/node/foo" to "/search/node/?find=foo"#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^search/node/(.+)$ /search/node/?find=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

This will internally redirect **/search/node/foo** to **/search/node/?find=foo** .

Comment: please see my example, I am looking for the opposite. From the parameter to the clean version

Comment: thanks, you are awesome! Been trying to figure this out for 6+ hours.